Quelle définition de « à » cadre avec « à » dans « au », dans « auprès » ?
« auprès » est « Composé de au et de près. Équivalent à l'ancien français emprès..  » Je sais que au = à + le.
Quelle acception de « à » dans Le Robert Dico En Ligne concorde le sens de « à », dans « au », dans « auprès » ?
Cette réaction de jilliagre n’aborde jamais cette question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Il me semble bien à moi que @jlliagre aborde « cette question » quand il écrit « au n'indique pas nécessairement une destination mais peut simplement indiquer un lieu », ce qui est le III 1. rapports de position / Position dans un lieu dans le lien donné.

@None Mais à quelle définition faites-vous référence, au lien ci-dessus, dans Le Robert Dico en ligne ?

Position dans un lieu (III.1)

a + le + près vous convient-il ?

@jcm69 Non, puisque je sais que au = à + le. Relire la deuxième phrase dans mon poste.

Selon moi, il s'agit dans le lien du Robert fourni, de la définition IV. 4. de la préposition à: complément circonstanciel d'accompagnement.
En effet, le TLFi indique parmi ses nombreux définitions et contextes de à/au, un usage de la préposition qui pouvait remplacer chez mais aussi auprès:
Tenez, informez-vous à votre prédécesseur de ce que vous avez à faire. - P. Mérimée, Théâtre de Clara Gazul, 1825
Aujourd'hui, on aurait dit: "auprès de votre prédécesseur"; c'est-à-dire que la personne devrait s'informer en étant en compagnie de son prédécesseur, et non dans son coin. Donc c'est bien cet usage-là du à qui a pu construire la locution auprès de; tout du moins ils ont un air de famille.
Or cette remarque-là est rangée sous la définition de à correspondant à l'usage de complément circonstanciel.
On retrouve dans notre langue incorrecte (ou ancienne?) des formulations telles que:

Je vais au coiffeur
Elle est partie au médecin

Qui correspondent au "chez le". Sur le même modèle, on pourrait avoir/a eu dans l'histoire de notre langue:
On courut chercher son fils unique qui étudiait aux Jésuites. - P. Mérimée, Portraits historiques et littéraires, 1870
Cet usage-là (toujours au même emplacement) signifie bien "auprès des".
